# Is there any way to add aria attributes to SVG Shape elements?

Tags: svg

I want to add aria attributes to svg shapes like circle, path etc to make it readable by screen readers.

Thanks.

Comment: So add them. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#WAIARIAAttributes